# Inserting Item in Database: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I tried to write a simple create-method like I build a several times, but this time, i get this error over and over:

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
```

I also tried the recommendet procedure in the link given by the exception:

```
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException dbex)
            {
                dbex.Entries.Single().Reload();
            }
```

But then following error occured the next:

```
Refresh cannot be used for entities in the Added state
```

What is understandable, I calling the Add-Method and so there should be nothing to refresh, right?

Most cases I found online are for the Update-method and so not what I'm looking for.

I also tried this, but the exception is not triggered by the error.
catch (DbUpdatableDataRecord ex)
{
return Json(ex.DataRecordInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

Model:

```
public class ForecastItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required( ErrorMessage = "Bitte ein Datum auswählen." )]
    [Display( Name = "Datum" )]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required( ErrorMessage = "Bitte ein Projekt auswählen." )]
    [Display( Name = "Projekt-ID" )]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Required( ErrorMessage = "Bitte einen Preis eingeben." )]
    [Display( Name = "Preis" )]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required( ErrorMessage = "Bitte einen Tickettyp hinterlegen." )]
    [Display( Name = "Tickettyp" )]
    public string TicketType { get; set; }

    [Required( ErrorMessage = "Bitte einen Abrechnungstyp auswählen." )]
    [Display( Name = "Abrechnungstyp" )]
    public string AccountingType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bitte ein Ziel-Projektvolumen angeben.")]
    [Display(Name = "Zielvolumen")]
    public int TargetVolume { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Projekt")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Method:

```
public JsonResult addForecastItem(string newDate, int newProjectId, int newForecastVolume, string newTicketType, string newCalcType, decimal newPrice)
    {
        ForecastItem fi = new ForecastItem
        {
            AccountingType = newCalcType,
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Price = newPrice,
            ProjectId = newProjectId,
            TargetVolume = newForecastVolume,
            TicketType = newTicketType
        };

        if ( ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                db.ForecastItems.Add(fi);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(e.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

        return Json(fi, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Any idea I made wrong here?
The Model is valid and the database inserts from other parts of the software.

Comment: The refresh updates the mapping file between the database tables and the c# code and uses the database as the source.  So if you added properties to the classes then you can't refresh those items.  It is best to add new columns to the database then refresh to update the classes.

Comment: @jarlh you are right, I have changed the tags

Comment: @jdweng thx for the explaination. But I'm afraid to say, I don't get the second part:
Could you please elaborate? Do you mean with " if you added properties to the classes" that I have something wrong in the annotaitions of my ForecastItem-Class? Or are you refferring to my getters and setters? What do you mean with adding columns, when my goal is to add new 'rows'? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh snap,

Error was: The ID wasn't incrementing automatically.
The table was created via SQL (to prototype, not prod) and the ID was an plain INT.

The [Key]-Attribute was added whily creating the class, but the database was not build new.

Solution:

1. Production, recommendet: Via Code First Migrations - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/][1]
2. CAUTION - Will delete all data: When data is irrelavant: Drop database and let the DbContext build the database on StartUp
3. My Solution (when no data is linked):

   ```
   alter table ForecastItems drop Column ID --drops column ID
   alter table ForecastItems add ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) -- creates column ID with` Autoincrement enabled
   ```